# Change a printer driver of an already configured printer

Tags: macos, printing, driver

Is there a way that you can set the printer driver for a printer that is already installed (other than deleting it an reinstalling). When you install a new printer you get an option to set which print driver it uses (see image below). But i cant seem to edit this once created.

[image: add printer option window]

Comment: I added within the tags the other versions which suffer the same **removed** function.

Answer (score 12):

This feature was removed in OS X 10.8. You have to use the CUPS interface by running `cupsctl WebInterface=yes` from Terminal and then pointing a Web browser to http://localhost:631. From there:

1. Open the Printers tab.
2. Select your printer and select Modify Printer from the second drop-down menu. (You’ll have to provide your OS credentials.)
3. Select your printer and click Continue twice.
4. Select a different driver or choose an appropriate PPD file.
5. Click Modify Printer.